# rearrangeLastN - Java

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes

I am struggling to understand given the below solution how the first half of the linked list is joined to the back end. I've ran through it logically but cannot understand the referencing of the last 3 lines.

Given a singly linked list of integers `l` and a non-negative integer `n`, move the last `n` list nodes to the beginning of the linked list.

For example, for the inputs `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `n = 3`, the output of `rearrangeLastN(l, n)`  should be
`[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`.

```
// Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
// class ListNode<T> {
//   ListNode(T x) {
//     value = x;
//   }
//   T value;
//   ListNode<T> next;
// }
//

ListNode<Integer> rearrangeLastN(ListNode<Integer> l, int n) {

    if (l == null || n == 0) return l;

    ListNode<Integer> fast = l; //1,2,3,4,5
    ListNode<Integer> slow = l; //1,2,3,4,5

    while(n > 0 && fast != null) { //3->2->1

        fast = fast.next; //4->5
        n--; //1
    }

    if (n >= 0 && fast == null) return l;

    while (fast.next != null) {  //1 Interation (4->5->null)
    
        slow = slow.next; //2->3->4->5
    
        fast = fast.next; //5
    }

    ListNode newHead = slow.next; //3->4->5

    slow.next = null; 

    fast.next = l; 

    return newHead;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
^
l
fast
slow
```

After the 1st `while` loop:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
^              ^
l         
               fast
slow
```

After the 2nd `while` loop:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
^    ^              ^
l         
                    fast
     slow
```

After the line `ListNode newHead = slow.next;`:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
^    ^    ^         ^
l         
                    fast
     slow newHead
```

After the line `slow.next = null;`:

```
1 -> 2 -> null    3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
^    ^            ^         ^
l         
                            fast
     slow         newHead
```

After the line `fast.next = l;`:

```
┌────────────────────────────────┐
└> 1 -> 2 -> null    3 -> 4 -> 5 ┘
   ^    ^            ^         ^
   l         
                               fast
        slow         newHead
```

Comment: Ahhh makes sense, thank you for the detailed diagram @ghchoi

Comment: @Webbo Thank you too, buddy!